# Quantum secure algorithms

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, post-quantum-cryptography, integrity, remote-data-checking

I want to know if the below algorithm , secure against quantum computing attack, and how I can compute the running time for the original algorithm and the proposed attack

[image: further fixed image]

---

Source: Yan Zhu, HuaiXi Wang, ZeXing Hu, Gail-Joon Ahn & HongXin Hu, [*Zero-knowledge proofs of retrievability*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.700.9758&rep=rep1&type=pdf), in [Sci. China Inf. Sci. 54, 1608](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11432-011-4293-9) (2011).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if the below algorithm , secure against quantum computing attack

No, it's not secure against Quantum Computers.  To quote the text: the secret key is $sk = x \in_R \mathbb{Z}_p$ and the public key is $pk = (g, v = g^x)$.

Shor's algorithm will directly recover the secret key from the public key; that runs in polynomial time.

Comment: even that p and g are secret sand unknown to the adversary?

Comment: @Shima: $g$ is not unknown to the adversary - it's right there in the public key.  As for $p$, well, that can be recovered (or at least, a multiple of it) by doing point counting on the curve (and Shor's can also directly recover it, but that'd be more effort...)

Comment: how is can be modified to post-quantum secure algorithm, any clue!

Comment: @Shima: doesn't look likely - it uses a pairing operation - I can't think of a post-quantum pairing operation off the top (don't the idea of a 'pairing operation' imply a group; discrete logs in a group are not postquantum), and revising it not to use a pairing operation isn't a "modification", but closer to a complete redesign...